# Numbers in hyphenation rules

Tags: hunspell, hyphenation

English Hyphenation file looks something like this...

```
LEFTHYPHENMIN 2
RIGHTHYPHENMIN 3
COMPOUNDLEFTHYPHENMIN 2
COMPOUNDRIGHTHYPHENMIN 3
.a2ch4
.ad1d4
.am5at
```

1, 2, 4 and 5 numbers are added next to characters.
Does it mean it is OK to hyphenate next to "a" but not OK to hyphenate next to "ad"?